# How to enable toolbar controls after open navigation view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, navigationview

Hi I'm new on android studio and I'm working with the NavigationView of support library design 22.2.1 , I rememeber that before we use to use the template of navigation drawer activity that android studio has.

With the last method (template) we can use the buttons onthe toolbar:

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmMfr.png"

But with the new method ww can't:

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhwp.png"

Also I will add some buttons to the toolbar and a second navigation view (right) that should be under the toolbar.

I don't kown if there is any method that could help me to this.

My code in my activity_main.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height_kitkat"
        android:background="?colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_height_lollipop"
        android:background="?colorPrimaryDark" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/status_bar_height">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2000dp"
        android:background="@color/md_red_500" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Inbox"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@color/md_text" />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme" />
<!--app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"-->
```

It's inside of an android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout with android:fitsSystemWindows (true).

My onCreate main Activity is:

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }
    setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
```

I'll appreciate your help!
Best regards.